# What is the purpose of invitations on Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs, invitation

I have received five invitations on Stack Overflow Careers.

What are they?

Whom should I send them to?

What is the purpose of these invitations?

Comment: If you have too many of them, I'll gladly help you receiving one :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea behind these invitations is that good developers generally know other good developers! These invitations are for you to extend to people who might be interested in joining our database of developers!

Comment: Can they be disabled?

Comment: @Tim What do you mean by "disabled"? If you don't want to use them, you don't have to...are you asking if you can disable notifications that you have new invitations available to send?

Comment: @Laura it sounds like the emails just arrive - am I getting the wrong impression?

Comment: @Tim All of our emails should have an unsubscribe link in the footer; that is how you disable emails from Careers. (If you find an email that doesn't have an unsubscribe link, let us know.) We *also* send an inbox notification to your Stack Overflow inbox when we grant new invitations - you cannot disable that notification, but they should be very infrequent.