# What are the benefits of Stack Overflow Careers invitations and why are only a limited number issued?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs, invitation

After I received some invitations, I didn't know what to do with them. I asked [a question about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256334/what-is-the-purpose-of-invitations-on-stack-overflow-careers) and I got the answer that as a developer I might know some good developers. But still something is missing:

1. If the invitations are to attract good developers why do we get a limited number of invitations? I have got 5 invitations, why shouldn't I be able to invite more than 5 developers?
2. I was member of Stack Overflow Careers for more than a year but I got the invitations somehow like a reward for completing my profile. If invitations are just for attracting good developers they shouldn't be limited. Secondly imagine that I invited some developers, **does the quality of invited developers have effect on me and my careers account?** If yes then I should just keep these invitations for some special people as I just have limited number of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quality of the developers you invite have no bearing on you or your account.

Once a user has shown some commitment and understanding of the Stack Overflow Careers site, we grant them invitations because we think they're more likely to use them appropriately.

Stack Overflow Careers profiles are for **developers only**.  Once you've filled out your profile and know the lay of the land, it's much more likely you'll send invitations to the appropriate people (which in this case, is any developer).  We get a lot of people who try and sign up for a profile who aren't developers, and if we allow them to create and publish a profile, it's bad for everyone.  They'll have a bad experience because they're in the wrong place, and employers looking at profiles will wonder why these non-developers are showing up in their searches.

Just FYI - This is the current reasoning/system in place.  We're working on a new system to maintain the quality and relevance of the database, while not making it so arduous to actually get a profile.

Edit:  Also, the 5 invitations is arbitrary.  If you'd like more, we'd be happy to grant them to you.

Comment: nope actually I don't need more but I was curious why shouldn't I be able to invite as much people as I can (if I knew more developers) and as I get from your answer you want to somehow let us know that just invite most appropriate people and not everyone you like